# Spring @Transactional preventing @Autowired in @Service

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I have a service with a bunch of `@Autowired` services. When I changed one of the methods to be `@Transactional`, it prevented all of the `@Autowired` as they are all null.

**Example:**

```
@Service
open class UserService {
    @Autowired
    private val userRepository : UserRepository? = null

    @Autowired
    private val emailService : EmailService? = null

    @Transactional
    @Throws(EmailConflictException::class)
    open fun insert(newUser: User, context : RequestContext) {
        if(!isEmailAvailable(newUser.email)) throw EmailConflictException()
        val user = userRepository!!.insert(newUser, context.org.id)
        emailService!!.send(userEmailFactory!!.getInviteEmail(user))
    }
}
```

Both emailService and userRepository are null during runtime upon calling insert. If I removed the `@Transactional` from the insert method then both emailService and userRepository are defined during runtime.

Why is this happening? How do I fix it

Comment: The first step is always to use constructor injection instead of field injection. Don't allow your dependencies to be null in the first place. You don't need any special handling to do this; simply declare them as ordinary properties, and Spring will understand to inject them in the constructor.

Comment: I appreciate the advice! In spite the new constructor they are still null even with the `?` removed.

`@Service open class UserService(private val userRepository: UserRepository, private val emailService : EmailService) {`

Comment: I also tried the syntax: `@Service open class UserService @Autowired constructor(private val userRepository: UserRepository, private val emailService : EmailService) {`

Comment: What kotlin and springboot version are you using?

Comment: It should not be _possible_ for them to be null when you have only the single constructor (`@Autowired` is not needed in that case). Show the code where you are _using_ `UserService`.

Comment: It might appear `null` but it isn't `null`. Probably your method ends up being `final` and as a `final` method cannot be proxied it ends up calling the method on the dynamic proxy instead of passing it along the enclosing object. The proxy is just a dummy with nothing set, it will only start a transaction and pass along the call. So you need to figure out why that method becomes final (despite the `open` in your declaration).

Comment: Even though this won't fix the problem, it's recommended to use `plugin.spring` plugin. https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#gradle

Comment: @LaksithaRanasingha That does actually fix my problem. Thank you!

Comment: @MikeVacchina that's good news. I have undeleted my original answer as that has actually fixed the issue. Could you please accept? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is normally caused by not having the `plugin.spring` plugin in the project. This is because Kotlin classes & members are `final` by default which conflicts with Spring AOP (i.e such as proxing DB transactions).

The `plugin.spring` is a wrapper of `kotlin-allopen` and includes the Spring annotations like `@Transactional`.

Try adding `plugin.spring` in your project. For example; a working config looks like below.

```
plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.4.2"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.11.RELEASE"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.4.21"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.4.21"
}
```

Here's the documentation - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/all-open-plugin.html#gradle

Note: the question shows that the class & the function are open. In theory, it should be sufficient. But as the OP doesn't show the complete project setup and how this code gets invoked. It's not sure why the `open` function doesn't get the correctly initialised bean.

Comment: his class is declared as `open`, hence it is not final and `kotlin-allopen` would not make any difference. I do agree that using allopen is a lot simpler than writing open to all the classes that need it.

Comment: @Alex.T as per Mike's comment, this has actually resolved the issue.

Comment: huh, that is quite odd, would be nice to know which of the changes provided by all-open helped, since the `open` was already there. Btw, can't change the vote unless the answer is edited.

Comment: I have just added a note. Indeed, it's quite odd. In theory, the open modifier should be sufficient. But I guess there should be more to this, as we haven't seen how this code gets invoked and the setup. @Mike how do you invoke this function?

Comment: Thanks @Alex.T, like to get to the bottom of this.

Answer (score 0):

I think Deinum has the right idea. To add some flavor, read up on CgLib vs. Dynamic Proxying as a concept.

https://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2006/12/29/spring-aop-cglib-or-jdk-dynamic-proxies.html

As one cheap thing you might also try, as counter-intuitive as it might feel, try adding "setters" and "getters" to your private variables.

Then, instead of referencing userRepository.insert... directly, change it to use getUserRepository().insert...

In this manner, by having getters/setters exposed, Spring's calls to set with the setter and return with the getter centralize better on the same ultimatel proxy target so you're both hitting the same private variables instead of the direct-accessing at the dummy proxy-wrapper's not-initialized variables.

Let me know if this helps!